# Could not find artifact javafx-packager:javafx-packager:jar:1.8.0_20 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14/../lib/ant-javafx.jar -> [Help 1]

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I am new to JavaFx and having this problem that " Could not find artifact javafx-packager:javafx-packager:jar:1.8.0_20 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14/../lib/ant-javafx.jar -> [Help 1]" . I am not able to figure out how to resolve the problem. I have included all the dependencies in the pom.xml file. My pom.xml file is as follows.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-## Heading ##4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.Lester</groupId>
<artifactId>ES_query</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>14</source>
                <target>14</target>
                <release>14</release>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.Lester.App</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!--
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>

                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDir>src/main/scala</sourceDir>
                            <testSourceDir>src/main/test</testSourceDir>
                        </configuration>

                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        -->

    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>scala-tools.org</id>
        <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>scala-tools.org</id>
        <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<properties>
    <scala.version>2.11</scala.version>
    <spark.version>2.4.1</spark.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>6.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven/maven-plugin-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/transport -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zenjava/javafx-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-hadoop</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.vegas-viz/vegas
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.vegas-viz</groupId>
        <artifactId>vegas_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.11</version>
    </dependency>
    -->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zenjava/javafx-maven-plugin -->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-convert</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.knockdata/spark-highcharts -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.knockdata</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-highcharts</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.6</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @bsheps I am trying to build the project using 'mvn install' command  on command prompt and this error shows up.

Comment: The solution is quite simple. JDK14 does not include javafx-packager anymore. Use the new jpackage tool which comes with JDK14.